# Upcasting FirefoxBrowser to Webdriver

Tags: selenium2, java

When we write the code to automate the browser then what is the need of upcasting in the code

```
Webdriver Some_Variable = new FirefoxDriver(); //Run time Polymorphism
```

My question: What is the need to do this? Can't we just do this:

```
FirefoxDriver Some_Variable = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Note: I already know that `FirefoxDriver` is a class which implements a WebDriver interface.

I already know if after casting, I will have access only to the current reference type class members even our object is from `FireFoxDriver` and our reference of `WebDriver`. Any unique class member in `FireFoxDriver` will not be visible to me.

Comment: Although your question is about Selenium which is a tool for testing, your question is not about testing and I voted to close it as offtopic. The Selenium documentation ( https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver ) states to use it like  this. You should also elaborate why you want to use the unique class members at all, now it just sounds a bit theoretical. Maybe its better to ask on the Selenium developer forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-developers

Comment: I agree with the request to edit more information in, but I don't agree that a programming problem that arises specifically because of this makes it a bad question. It's a bit of a blur between SO, but that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good programming practice to type the variable to be the the least-specific subclass that you actually care about.  That way, your code is more reusable.

In your case, if you actually need to call methods on `FirefoxDriver` that aren't defined on `Webdriver`, you should type `Some_Variable` to be `FirefoxDriver`.  If you don't need to do anything Firefox-specific, you should type `Some_Variable` to be `Webdriver`.  That way, it will be easier to use the same code with `ChromeDriver` or `InternetExplorerDriver` or whatever.

If you aren't sure whether you need Firefox-specific methods, start by typing `Some_Variable` to be `Webdriver`, because you *are* sure you will need to use `Webriver` methods.